# Case notation and integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, notation, distribution-theory

I am trying to learn about case functions, and how to represent certain expressions.

Say we are given a function and a domain on which it is valid. for example:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=1/x, (x>0)
\end{equation}

Furthermore, suppose we want to extend to the entire real line:
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
-\dfrac{1}{x},& x<0;\\
0,& x=0;\\
\dfrac{1}{x},& x>0;\\
\end{cases}
$$
where we set the function equal to zero at $x=0$.

Now, it should be possible to sum multiple shifted versions of this. for example, suppose we had:
$$f_1(x)=f(x-h_1)=
\begin{cases}
-\dfrac{1}{x-h_1},& x<h_1;\\
0,& x=h_1;\\
\dfrac{1}{x-h_1},& x>h_1;\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$f_2(x)=f(x-h_2)=
\begin{cases}
-\dfrac{1}{x-h_2},& x<h_2;\\
0,& x=h_2;\\
\dfrac{1}{x-h_2},& x>h_2;\\
\end{cases}
$$
Where $f_1$ is shifted by $h_1$ and $f_2$ is shifted by $h_2$. An expression such as $f(x-h_1)+f(x-h_2)$ should be valid on the entire real line.

I am having difficulty understanding how we can express a continuous version of this. for example if we wanted to integrate (edit: by this i mean continually sum-up the shifted versions of these functions over an interval, not integrate the function per-se) over all such $f(x-h)$'s where $h$ ran over a continuous interval, how would we express that integral?

EDIT: (this is edit/updated question is based off of discussion in the comments)
if we define
$$g(x)=\int_a^bf(x-h)dh$$ we may run into a problem because $f(x)$ is like $1/x$ and not Riemann integrable. is it then possible to make sense of the concept as a distribution/generalized function? so for a test function $\phi(x)$.
$$g(x)=\langle \phi(x),\int f(x-h)dh\rangle $$

Comment: It will be easier to write $f(x-h_1)+f(x-h_2)$ with some assumptions, like $h_1<h_2.$ Also, you seem to mean: $$f_1(x)=f(x-h_1)=\dots$$ You’ve written instead $f_1(x-h_1)=\dots$ which would mean $f_1(x)=f(x).$

Comment: Without knowing $h_1<h_2$ or $h_2<h_1$ or $h_2=h_1,$ you will need $9=3\times 3$ cases.

Comment: thank you... this is very helpful... trying to update with appropriate edits.

Comment: i suppose what i am after is a more parsimonious way to express this- s.t. we can sum over a continuum of these $f(x-h_i)$'s

Comment: Why does $\int_a^b f(x-h) \,\mathrm{d}h$ not express "integrate over all such $f$s where $h$ ran over a continuous interval"?  Here, the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: @EricTowers, so if we had $g(x)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x-h)dh$, this integrates over all h $[a,b]$ and $g(x)$ is valid for all x because each $f(x-h)$ is? that could be it.

Comment: @DFlemming yes, that would be the way to do things in general. The only trouble for your particular example is that the function $g$ is not always well-defined, because $f$ is not Riemann-integrable on every compact interval in $\Bbb{R}$. For example, if $a=-1,b=1$ and $x=0$, then the expression you wrote down doesn't make sense since it would be $g(0)=\int_{-1}^{1}f(-h)\,dh$, but $f(-h)$ is like $\frac{1}{h}$, which is not integrable (not even improperly) near the origin. If for example you made things bounded, such as $\gamma(x)=\int_a^b\sin(f(x-h))\,dh$, then this would be well-defined.

Comment: @peek-a-boo ty for the comment. i made the function not Riemann-integrable on purpose. i think this is the core of my confusion: i understand that the function is like $\dfrac{1}{h}$, but i am not integrating the function, just adding many shifted versions of it (which we can rationalize if there were, say 2 as in my example, by adding specific cases). is the issue that once we pass from adding a finite number of these to a continuum, things go wrong? is there another way to handle the continuous case?

Comment: @peek-a-boo, just had a thought: could something like this work as a distribution? so, $g(x)=\langle \phi(x),\int f(x-h)dh\rangle$, where $\phi$ is a test function

Answer (score 1):

Again, the symbol $\int f(x-h)\,dh$ makes no sense without you being more careful. Perhaps what you're after is the (Cauchy) principal-value distribution: for any Schwartz function $\phi\in \mathcal{S}(\Bbb{R})$, we define
\begin{align}
\left\langle \text{p.v.}\left(\frac{1}{(\cdot)}\right), \phi\right\rangle:=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{|x|>\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,dx.
\end{align}
It is of course tradition to denote the distribution as $\text{p.v.}\frac{1}{x}$... the letter $x$ there is just an arbitrary place-holder, which is why for the sake of definition, I used the $(\cdot)$ notation.
Now, one can consider the convolution of this principal value distribution with any Schwartz-function $\phi$ to get
the  (smooth) function whose value at a point $y\in\Bbb{R}^n$ is
\begin{align}
\left[\left(\text{p.v.}\frac{1}{x} \right)*\phi \right](y)&:=
\left\langle \text{p.v.}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), \phi(y-\cdot)\right\rangle\\
&:=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{|t|>\epsilon}\frac{\phi(y-t)}{t}\,dt\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{|x-s|>\epsilon}\frac{\phi(s)}{x-s}\,ds.
\end{align}
(up to some constant factors of $i,\pi$ etc this is the Riesz transform of $\phi$).
Note that no matter how much extra machinery we try to invoke, we still cannot escape the singularity of $\frac{1}{x}$ at the origin. That is why in everything above, to ensure everything is well-defined, we have to integrate an $\epsilon$-distance away from the singularity and then take the limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$.

More generally, if $\Omega\in L^1(S^{n-1})$ and $\int_{S^{n-1}}\Omega\,d\sigma=0$ (integral with respect to surface measure on the unit sphere in $n$-dimensions), then one can define the principal value distribution $\text{p.v.}\frac{\Omega(\hat{x})}{|x|^n}$, where $\hat{x}=\frac{x}{|x|}$ is the normalized vector, by defining for each Schwartz function $\phi\in \mathcal{S}(\Bbb{R}^n)$,
\begin{align}
\left\langle\text{p.v.}\frac{\Omega(\hat{x})}{|x|^n}, \phi\right\rangle&:=
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{|x|>\epsilon}\frac{\Omega(\hat{x})}{|x|^n}\phi(x)\,dx
\end{align}
One can verify this is actually continuous with respect to the topology on the space of Schwartz functions, so this defines a tempered distribution. Note that this generalizes what we talked about before, because when $n=1$, $S^{n-1}=S^0=\{-1,1\}$ consists of two points, and integrating over these points just means adding up the two function values; so in the above example, we had $\Omega(u)=\text{sgn}(u)$, i.e $\Omega(-1)=-1, \Omega(u)=1$, so it's just the identity function on $\{-1,1\}$, and thus for $x\neq 0$, we have $\frac{\Omega(\hat{x})}{|x|}=\frac{1}{x}$.

Now, we can once again consider the convolution of this distribution with a Schwartz function $\phi$ to get a smooth function
\begin{align}
\left[\left(\text{p.v.}\frac{\Omega(\hat{x})}{|x|^n} \right)*\phi \right](y)&:=
\left\langle \text{p.v.}\left(\frac{\Omega(\hat{x})}{|x|^n}\right), \phi(y-\cdot)\right\rangle\\
&:=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{|t|>\epsilon}\frac{\Omega(\hat{t})}{|t|^n}\phi(y-t)\,dt\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{|y-s|>\epsilon}\frac{\Omega(\widehat{y-s})}{|y-s|^n}\phi(s)\,ds.
\end{align}
Of course, here the $dt,ds$ mean integrals with respect to the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: thanks for the response... i'll have the spend some time with this.... i do appreciate it